# Is there a way to filter calendar results by location?

Tags: plugin-solspacecalendar

My current calendar plugin has filters by category, location and a date selector. Is this all achievable in solspace calendar?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can achieve this by using the [`search` parameter](https://docs.solspace.com/craft/calendar/v3/template-functions/calendar.events.html#param-search) on `calendar.events` just like you would with regular [Craft Searching](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/searching.html).

```
search: "customField:myvalue*"
```

It might also look something like this in your template:

```
{% set eventOptions = {
  rangeStart: 'now',
  rangeEnd: '3 months',
} %}

{% set events = craft.calendar.events(eventOptions).search("location:test") %}

{% for event in events %}
   ...
{% endfor %}
```